# SMS intercept on iPhone without jailbreak

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sms, app-store

Some know if there is a way to intercept incoming SMS on iPhone Device, with out jailbreak??

So, If it is posible, when I send the App for the Appstore, there is a way to explain and demonstrate to apple that the application access to SMS for a good purpose, with out compromise the user security??

Any advice will be useful for me.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

You might want to browse CoreTelephony for the related things that are exposed. As you might imagine, it's a pretty small framework.